# Finding and invoking a generic overloaded method

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, invoke, overloading

How can I find a generic overloaded method? For example, `Queryable`'s

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> Select<TSource , TResult> ( this IQueryable<TSource> source , Expression<Func<TSource , int , TResult>> selector );
```

I've looked for existing solutions, and they're either not generic enough (are based on the method's parameters count, etc.), need more parameters than I have (require generic type definitions or arguments), or just plain wrong (don't account for nested generics, etc.)

I have the defining class type — `Type type`, the method name — `string name` and the array of the parameter types (not the generic definitions) — `Type[] types`.

So far it seems I have to map each of prospective method's `.GetGenericArguments()` to a specific type by comparing the (generic type tree?) of the method's `.GetParameters ().Select (p=>p.ParameterType)` with the corresponding item in the `types` array, thus deducing the generic arguments of the method, so I can `.MakeGenericMethod` it.

This seems a bit too complicated for the task, so maybe I'm overthinking the whole thing.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I just coded this, which is essentially a manual type inference, and I think should do what I need.

```
public static class TypeExtensions {

    public static Type GetTypeDefinition ( this Type type ) {
        return type.IsGenericType ? type.GetGenericTypeDefinition () : type;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetImproperComposingTypes ( this Type type ) {
        yield return type.GetTypeDefinition ();
        if ( type.IsGenericType ) {
            foreach ( var argumentType in type.GetGenericArguments () ) {
                foreach ( var t in argumentType.GetImproperComposingTypes () ) yield return t;
            }
        }
    }

    private static Dictionary<Type , Type> GetInferenceMap ( ParameterInfo[] parameters , Type[] types ) {
        var genericArgumentsMap = new Dictionary<Type , Type> ();
        var match = parameters.All ( parameter => parameter.ParameterType.GetImproperComposingTypes ().Zip ( types[parameter.Position].GetImproperComposingTypes () ).All ( a => {
            if ( !a.Item1.IsGenericParameter ) return a.Item1 == a.Item2;
            if ( genericArgumentsMap.ContainsKey ( a.Item1 ) ) return genericArgumentsMap[a.Item1] == a.Item2;
            genericArgumentsMap[a.Item1] = a.Item2;
            return true;
        } ) );
        return match ? genericArgumentsMap : null;
    }

    public static MethodInfo MakeGenericMethod ( this Type type , string name , Type[] types ) {
        var methods = from method in type.GetMethods ()
                      where method.Name == name
                      let parameters = method.GetParameters ()
                      where parameters.Length == types.Length
                      let genericArgumentsMap = GetInferenceMap ( parameters , types )
                      where genericArgumentsMap != null
                      where method.GetGenericArguments ().Length == genericArgumentsMap.Keys.Count ()
                      select new {
                          method ,
                          genericArgumentsMap
                      };
        return methods.Select ( m => m.method.IsGenericMethodDefinition ? m.method.MakeGenericMethod ( m.method.GetGenericArguments ().Map ( m.genericArgumentsMap ).ToArray () ) : m.method ).SingleOrDefault ();
    }

}
```

So given

```
public class Foos {
    public void Foo<T1 , T2 , T3> ( int a , T1 b , IEnumerable<T2> c , Expression<Func<T1 , T3 , string>> d ) {
    }
    public void Foo<T1 , T2 , T3> ( int a , T1 b , IEnumerable<T2> c , Expression<Func<T1 , T3 , int>> d ) {
    }
    public void Foo () {
    }
    public void Foo ( string s ) {
    }
}
```

I can pick the method I want:

```
var method = typeof ( Foos ).MakeGenericMethod ( "Foo" , new[] { typeof ( int ) , typeof ( DateTime ) , typeof ( IEnumerable<string> ) , typeof ( Expression<Func<DateTime , double , int>> ) } );
method.Invoke ( new Foos () , new object[] { 1 , DateTime.Now , null , null } );

var method = typeof ( Foos ).MakeGenericMethod ( "Foo" , Type.EmptyTypes );
method.Invoke ( new Foos () , new object[] { } );

var method = typeof ( Foos ).MakeGenericMethod ( "Foo" , new[] { typeof ( string ) } );
method.Invoke ( new Foos () , new object[] { "zozo" } );
```

This seem to support non-generic methods, but doesn't support explicit generic arguments (obviously), and maybe needs some work, but that's the core of it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you have to basically look through all the methods. There's no way of getting straight to a generic method just by specifying the number of type parameters etc.

However, one thing you *can* use is the fact that overloads with the same signature other than genericity are only overloaded by the *number* of generic type parameters. You can't use constraints or type parameter names to have:

```
 void Foo<T1>(String x)
 void Foo<T2>(String y)
```

etc.

Yes, this is all pretty complicated. I'd try pretty hard to avoid needing to do it if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

Calling generic methods with reflection genuinely can be this ugly. To resolve the correct `MethodInfo` I normally try to pick the simplest unique factor and work with that - which might mean the number of generic-parameters / method-parameters, etc. I try to avoid having to compare the unbound generic types themselves.

With `dynamic` in 4.0, I *believe* (although I'd need to check) that this can make many of these calls simpler (since it essentially does the method/generic resolution at runtime), but it doesn't work for extension methods ;-(

<s>Another option is `Expression`, which can be a bit prettier in some ways, but you need to `Compile()` it etc, and `Expression` is *itself* complicated.</s> (actually, forget that - it is still hard)

Answer (score 0):

When you call GetMethod or InvokeMember on a Type instance, you are able to pass an custom subclass of the [Binder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.binder.aspx) class. A custom binder can alter the way members are selected, as they receive a list of candidate members to pick from.